# Is it necessary that Minimum/Maximum Heap must be a Binary Heap?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees, binary-trees, heaps

I find this extremely wrong, that a lot of books, articles, video tutorials, online courses or trainers define Minimum/Maximum Heap data structure as a particular type of the Binary Heap data structure.. however! according to the definition of what is `Heap` Data Structure, that's wrong! Heap can be perfectly fine either Binary or non-Binary.

I have also read this in some Google Engineer's blog, that my thoughts are correct on this.

Any take? maybe I'm wrong? nothing, at all, restricts the Minimum/Maximum Heap that they must be necessary Binary Heap variations. Node can have 3 children, and it would still fit the Minimum/Maximum Heap definition.

Question is: how do you think? am I wrong or not? what's your take on this?

Comment: What is a heap for you? This is the root of the question. I'm not sure there is a single agreed upon formal definition of *heap*.

Comment: Tree-based data structure, which satisfies Heap order invariant (either max, min, or etc.). Yes, that's what I'm asking.. that nothing says, that Heap is a necessarily Binary-Tree based data structure.

Comment: So your definition doesn't specify the number of children. Therefore, under your definition, we tautologically have that a heap need not be a binary tree.

Comment: That's my question - is my definition correct? :) this is what I've read in 2 books and few nice Engineers' blogs.. :) can we have, in an Exact Science, like Computer Science, a very specific and concrete definition of - What is the Heap, then?

Comment: You're assuming that there is a single, accepted upon definition. I'm not sure your assumption is correct.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming so.. because it's Computer Science.. and not Geography or History.. we must have a clear and sharp discrete definition.. if we don't - then it's very pity.. by the way, what's your knowledge on the definition of the Heap Data Structure?

Comment: There isn't even an agreed upon definition of standard models such as DFA and Turing machine.

Comment: I would use "binary heap". See for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap).

Comment: So, you would've defined Max/Min heaps as implementations of Binary Heap.. got it. But it's still very pity, that I'm lacking the formal/official definition, on which I can stand on.

Comment: You can have more than two children in a heap, if you want. You can have 1 to n children, and in a binary heap we have one or two children. Usually we use binary heaps.

Answer (score 1):

A heap can be binary or k-ary, so it's fine to think like you do, in my opinion. Binary heaps are more common to think about. The time complexities for the different heap operations change for the better or worse as we vary k.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "heap", think "priority queue". A priority queue is a data structure where elements can be inserted in any order, but are removed in key order.

We will suppose that the priority queue uses a comparison operator (say, less-than) to determine key order. (This need not be the case; if the keys are integers, for example, you could use a radix operator.) We will further suppose that it is a min-queue, where elements are removed in ascending order (that is, the first element is the minimum).

Then simply reversing the sense of the comparison operator gives a max-queue.

Heaps (in their many forms) are one way of implementing priority queues, just like how balanced binary search trees (in their many forms) are one way of implementing key-value dictionaries. But they are not the only way.